# How do you prove that for $|x−x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f'(x)−f'(x_0)|<\epsilon$.

Tags: limits, derivatives, continuity, epsilon-delta

How do you prove that for $|x−x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f'(x)−f'(x_0)|<\epsilon$, when $g'(x)$ is continuous.

I know that $|x−x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)−f(x_0)|<\epsilon$, but I'm seeing proofs that require it works for the derivative of f as well. How does that work?

Comment: This is false in general. There are differentiable functions with discontinuous derivative.

Comment: See this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112067/how-discontinuous-can-a-derivative-be

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative

Comment: And, when searching for such a function, whose derivative is discontinuous, you might find it among the first derivatives of functions whose second derivative is discontinuous.

Comment: I gave you the links that follow @IvoTerek 's comment.

Comment: I think the question is incomplete. Please have a relook at it.

Comment: I have edited it to include that g'(x) is contin.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1029374/721644)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
Think of a discontinuous function, and integrate it. Then you'll find a counter-example.

Comment: Well just choosing any discontinuous function won't work. You have to choose a function with essential discontinuity. Note that the integrated function may be not be differentiable at points where original function is discontinuous. Also see this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3516923/72031

Comment: And this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3518190/72031

Comment: @ParamananSingh, thank you for the remark and links! I'll examine them carefully.