# How to find the anti-derivative is $\left|x\right|$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Let the function $f(x) = \cases{1 & x>0 \\ -1 & x<0}$. I want to show that the anti-derivative of $f(x)$ is $\left|x\right|$.

Let's split to cases:
If $x\le 0$ then $F(x) = \int_{-1}^x f(x) = \int_{-1}^x (-1) = (x+1)(-1) = -x - 1$
If $x\ge 0$ then $F(x) = \int_{-1}^0 f(x) + \int_0^xf = -1 + x$

Now, it doesn't look like $\left|x\right|$. I've been told to use $F(x) = 1 + \int_{-1}^x f$ but I don't understand the rationality behind that.

Comment: 1. Is there some reason not to take $F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t)\, dt$, which _is_ $|x|$? 2. To be pedantic, $F(x) = |x|$ is not an antiderivative of your $f$, it's only an antiderivative at every non-zero real number. (This nitpick could well matter if you try to apply a theorem that presumes $F$ is an antiderivative.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem is the notion of ***THE*** antiderivative. There are many antiderivatives for your function (any two of which differ by a constant).

In other words, if $F' = f$, then $(F + C)' = f$ as well, where $C$ is any constant.

In your case, the function $F$ you've computed is indeed *an* antiderivative of $f$, but picking $C = 1$ leads to a more simply expressed antiderivative, namely $G(x) = |x|$.

N.B. user86418's comment is an excellent point: $F$ is not an antiderivative for $f$ at $x = 0$, because at $x = 0$, $F$ is not differentiable, and hence it's impossible for $F'(0) = f(0)$. But on $K = \mathbb R - \{0\}$, what I've said is correct...but not quite complete. Since there's function $H$ with $H' = f$ everywhere (you just can't make it work at zero! See below.), you're limited to antiderivatives on $K$ (the punctured real line). And if $P$ and $Q$ are two antiderivatives on $K$, then $F$ and $G$ differ by a constant *on each component of $K$*. You could, for instance, have taken your antiderivative $F$, and built 
$$
P(x) = \begin{cases} F(x)-4 & x \le 0 \\ F(x) + 13 & x > 0 \end{cases}
$$
and had an equally good antiderivative (on $K$).

How do I know that there's no antiderivative on all of $\mathbb R$? Because "derivatives have the intermediate value property": if $h$ is differentiable at every point of some interval $[a, b]$, with $h'(a) = A$ and $h'(b) = B$, then for any $C$ between $A$ and $B$, there's a point $c \in [a, b]$ with $h'(c) = C$.

That result seems pretty surprising to me every time I see it. It's known as Darboux's Theorem. (See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54843/how-to-prove-that-derivatives-have-the-intermediate-value-property), along with its comments and answers, for further enlightenment.)

Comment: Typo in "there's a point $c \in [a, b]$ with $h'(c) = c$.", I think; (It should be  "there's a point $c \in [a, b]$ with $h'(c) = C$").

Comment: Fixed; thanks! $ $

Comment: A question. Why do we have to use limits while integrating? Why not directly integrate the function? It gives the answer directly. For x<0 we get the integral to be -x and in the other case it is x

Comment: @GummyBears: I think you need to review the notion of antiderivative and its relation to the definite integral, which is characterized by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. What if I'd said, "Why not directly integrate the function: for $x < 0$ we get the integral to be $-x + 13$ and in the other case it's $x - 7$,"? That statement is just as correct as yours is, but doesn't lead to the same nice result. That yours *does* lead to the "right" result might be regarded as a bit of luck, as much as anything, in the definition of absolute value.