# Does the inverse image of any open interval under the derivative of a function contain a non-empty interior?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Given any differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and an open interval $(a,b)$ contained in the range of the derivative $g:=f'$ of $f$, does $g^{-1}((a,b))$ have to contain a non-empty interior. Of course, $g$ is not necessarily continuous. But it has some nice properties: For example, we know that the set of continuity points of $g$ is of second category in $\mathbb{R}$ (by an argument based on Baire category theorem). In addition, $g$ has the intermediate value property by Darboux's theorem. i.e., mapping any interval into an interval. BTW, it is not an exercise or statement from any book. So, I wouldn't be surprised that there is a counterexample for it.

Comment: So, using the properties you know, can you attempt to solve the problem?  You should do it, not us.

Comment: @GEdgar I tried but can't find the answer or give a counter example. It is not an exercise.

Comment: @DehanChen This is [the key](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54843/how-to-prove-that-derivatives-have-the-intermediate-value-property)

Comment: @DehanChen A more [direct link to a proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29) (Wikipedia).

Comment: @Bettybel But it is just Darboux's theorem.  The question here is quite different from that. Or, you think one can follow the same argument?

Comment: So: try to show that any function with the Darboux property, regardless of whether it is a derivative, has your property.

Answer (score 2):

A [Pompeiu derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pompeiu_derivative) is a function that is the derivative of an everywhere differentiable function and that vanishes in a dense set. Taking $g$ to be a non-zero Pompeiu derivative taking some non-zero value $y$, the preimage of the open interval $(y-|y|,y+|y|)$ is non-empty but contains no interval.

Comment: Thx. I think you are right

Comment: This is of course wrong. Since $y$ should be such that $g$ takes that value but such that no other value inside $(y-|y|, y+|y|)$ is taken either.

Comment: @Bettybel: I think you mean "every other value is also taken", which I didn't notice was a condition. It's true that particular interval might not be contained in the image of $g$, but by Darboux's theorem the image of a non-zero Pompeiu derivative contains *some* open interval (which can be taken not to include 0).

Comment: I just find an interesting consequence about the function you construct. If $y:=g(x_0)\neq 0$, then $g$ has to be discontinuous at $x_0$. Otherwise, the continuity of $g$ at $x_0$ implies that $g^{-1}((y-|y|,y+|y|))$ is a  neighborhood of $x_0$.