# Function writen as two functions having IVP

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I heard this problem and I am a bit stuck.

Given a function $f : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an open interval.
Then $f$ can be writen $f=g+h$ where $g,h$ are defined in the same interval and have the Intermediate Value Property. I tried to construct firstly the one function arbitarily at two points and then tried to define it in a way to have the IVP but I cannot manage to control the other function, as I try to fix the one I destroy the other and I cannot seem to know how to be certain I have enough point to define both in a way they have the IVP.

Any help appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Theorem 9.5, [p.57](http://books.google.com/books?id=Cqk5AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA57) in van Rooij, Schikhof: A Second Course on Real Functions.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885580/is-every-real-valued-function-on-an-interval-a-sum-of-two-functions-with-interme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** In fact, all the information I give below (and more) is provided [in another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100096/references-about-sierpinskis-theorem-regarding-darboux-functions) in a much more organized way. I just found it.

**My original post:** The intermediate Value property is also called the Darboux property. Sierpinski first proved this theorem.The problem is treated in a blog of [Beni Bogosel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/7327/beni-bogosel), a member of our own community and in much more generality too.

http://mathproblems123.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/strange-functions.pdf

It is also proved in( As I found from Wikipedia)

Bruckner, Andrew M: Differentiation of real functions, 2 ed, page 6, American Mathematical Society, 1994

Comment: This is funny, because you linked to a blog of a member of MSE.

Comment: @mixedmath Thank you! Took me a moment to realize. :)

Comment: Thanks very much for the interesting link, and very elementary! Actually I knew about mr. Bogosel's blog he is doing very good work there.