# Uniqueness of exceptional function

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

I was reading some note of uniqueness of the exponential function. 
For every $a>0$ exists a unique $f: \mathbb{R} \to (0,\infty)$ such that 
(1) $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ 
(2) $f(1)=a$ 
(3) exists a rectangle in a the first or second quadrant that not contains the graphs. 
The question is: 
Which are the function that have a points with every rectangle in the first or second quadrant of the plane xy?

Comment: Your phrasing is unclear. Are you requesting a characterization of the functions $f$ for which there exist $a<b<0<c<d$ such that $f(a) f(b)$ and $f(c) f(d)$ are negative?  Or maybe something like $g(x)=\sin(1/x)$, which **intersects** every (axis-aligned) rectangle containing the origin?

Comment: You might look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3074999/function-whose-graph-is-dense-in-the-plane for functions whose graph intersects every rectangle.

Comment: The exponential function does not satisfy $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$; it satisfies $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$.

Comment: @Gonçalo Yes i edited. Thank you

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum not the text says that a function defined in that way there are infinite ones. Furthermore, there are infinite rectangles that contain the graph. But in the piano in general not only in the origin.