# Measure of big discontinuities

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $D\subset\left[  0,1\right]  $ be a dense set, and $\mu$ Lebesgue
measure on $\left[  0,1\right]  .$

Suppose $f:\left[  0,1\right]  \rightarrow\left[  0,1\right]  $ is continuous
at each point in $D.$ Let $\overline{G}$ be the closure of the graph of $f$ on $\left[
0,1\right]  ^{2}.$

Is it true that $\mu\left\{  x_{0}:\overline{G}\cap\left\{  x=x_{0}\right\}
\text{ is infinite}\right\}  =0?$

Comment: what does it mean by 'THE' borel probability measure on [0,1]?

Comment: I replaced "the Borel" by "Lebesgue". Hopefully this is what was meant.

Comment: Lebesgue is fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a counterexample: Let $D$ be the complement of a fat Cantor set $C \subseteq [0, 1]$ so $D$ is dense. Construct $f:[0, 1] \rightarrow [0, 1]$ such that $f$ is zero on $D$ and the graph of $f$ is dense in $C \times [0, 1]$.

Comment: I dont quite get the question. what is $\{x_0: \bar{G}\cap \{x=x_0\} \text{is infinite}\}$?

Comment: I guess it is the set of those $x \in [0, 1]$ such that the vertical section through $x$ meets $\overline{G}$ at infinitely many points.

Comment: I see. I didn't know about these functions that have dense graph, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Much worse than this is possible, which you can see by using #1 & #2 below.

**1.** There exist functions $f:{\mathbb R} \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ such that the graph of $f$ is dense in ${\mathbb R}^2.$ (In fact, this can even be the case for a Baire $2$ function.)

See, for example, these StackExchange questions:

[Graph of discontinuous linear function is dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131197/graph-of-discontinuous-linear-function-is-dense)

[Does there exist a function $f:[0,1] \to[0,1]$ such its graph is dense in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139791/does-there-exist-a-function-f0-1-to0-1-such-its-graph-is-dense-in-0-1?lq=1)

[graph is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227427/graph-is-dense-in-mathbbr2?lq=1)

**2.** Given any function $f:{\mathbb R} \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$, there exists a subset $D$ of $\mathbb R$ such that $D$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ and $f$ restricted to $D$ is continuous.

For this result, see the following:

[Every real function has a dense set on which its restriction is continuous](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72800/every-real-function-has-a-dense-set-on-which-its-restriction-is-continuous) [mathoverflow question]

Jack B. Brown, [*A measure theoretic variant of Blumberg's theorem*](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1977-066-02/S0002-9939-1977-0463377-4/), **Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society** 66 #2 (October 1977), 266-268.

[google search for "Blumberg" and "dense" and "continuous"](http://www.google.com/search?q=Blumberg+dense+continuous)

Comment: I think the OP is only considering functions which have a dense (and hence comeager) set of points of continuity. Blumberg's theorem only gives the continuity of any function _restricted_ to some dense set.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even notice that this could have been the interpretation, but in thinking about it now I tend to agree with you. Maybe the OP can reword it as "continuous at each point in $D$" if this is the intended meaning.

Comment: Thanks Dave, this is interesting and I was not aware of this result; hot_queen is right I meant continuous at every point in D.